# Groovy each immutability

Tags: groovy, immutability, xmlslurper

From the following code snippet I tried, This runs into an infinite loop regardless of the fact that I mark the initial ds as immutable, and looping it with an each. What am I missing? -

```groovy
domObject.Whatever.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Node' }.asImmutable().each { node -> //Bazinga
    nodes.split(/(;|,|\n|&)/).eachWithIndex { nodeName, index ->
        def newNode = new Node(null, node.name(), node.attributes(), node.value())
        newNode.@name = nodeName
        //I'm simply adding new nodes here
        node.parent().children().add(0, newNode)     //bazinga
    }
}
```

Ive used an xmlparser for the domObject.

Comment: `asImmutable()` returns an immutable copy of the collection. It does not make the original collection immutable.

Comment: in which case there must be no infinite loops - is that right/

Comment: where does 'nodes' in the inner closure come from?